# Low power switch with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, switches, low-power

I'm designing a light switch that will be controlled by a uC. The problem is that the uC will be connected to a coin battery cell (3,3v) and he can't waste energy in the switch circuit. So what would be a design that would have a low power consumption in the activation switch?

The light will be connected to the grid and it will draw a maximum of 10A.

Comment: Something MOSFET-based that draws most of its power from the circuit.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking a N MOSFET and P MOSFET in anti-parallel but that won't work.

Comment: You mean like a transmission gate?

Comment: Yes, like a transmission gate.

Comment: What is this uC drawing its commands from?

Comment: If you are driving a light on the grid, why not draw power from the grid instead of a coin cell with 3k series impedance

Comment: A coin battery cell won't power much of anything. Continuous draw should be in the hundreds of microamps, or less. 1 mA is about tops. (Though I'm not sure what battery chemistry gives you 3.3 V.) Even a MOC3063 needs 5 mA. You should consider using the power source itself, though that also takes care. I already did what you are doing, though it was to control a split-phase oven at 40 A.

Comment: The neutral wire won't pass through the switch so i only have the phase which will go directly to the light. So i can't use a power source or use series impedance. The uC will consume very little power and i'm willing to use multiple coin cells.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel sorry i didn't understand. You are refering to the power source of the uC? If so he's drawing from a coin cell battery.

Comment: They do have custom hybrid SSR's  that can operate with
 less than 150 uW and still be able to switch 3 kW but limited to 100Vdc with MOSFETs . Seriously under powered Try A CR123A

Comment: In a way what i'm asking is a low power SSR. I don't know any low power SSR but i will look into it. Well the CR123A is bigger and expensive but worth considering it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What about a solenoid on either side of a regular light switch? An initial power draw for each actuation but no prolonged power draw.

Comment: A solenoid would consume a lot of power from the battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are such things as [Latching, Sequence and Impulse Relays](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/357/105A_755-7090.pdf).  Most if not all such devices are designed to only require power when changing states.

There is also a [2 coil latching relay](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-2-Coil_Latching_Relay/).  I believe you momentarily energize one coil to turn it on and the other to turn it off.

Comment: They require a large amount of power to switch. From the pdf there's a  characteristic Minimum Switching Requirement: 100mA. That peak would be too high for the battery. But then again, is worth considering it if a use a more powerful battery.

As for the 2 coil latching relay i can't find a current consumption.

Comment: 2 different SSRs in a start/stop arrangement to energise a latching 110/240v relay for the light?

Comment: @LucasArruda if it is only for a short time, 100mA is not a problem, provided you have enough capacitance in parallel with the coin cell.

Comment: Lucas, I think @Joshyp00 has a good point.  You would control some sort of solid state relay (or other device like a triac) and switch mains power to flip the magnetic (latching) relays.  I suspect the current necessary to flip a triac is much smaller than that needed to flip a magnetic relay.

Comment: @st2000 well the latching would still consume a peak current from the coin cell. I think putting a parallel capacitor like dim suggest would do the trick. Thanks. And thank you Joshyp00 as well.

Comment: I think you missed it.  @Joshyp00 is suggesting you use something that takes far less current to control the latching relays (like a triac).  And you switch mains using the triac to supply the coils of the latching relay.  You use a latching relay that has coils rated for what ever mains AC power you have available.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a relay that has both contacts rated to 10A and a low coil wattage may be difficult/costly but I'm sure they are out there. The output signals from your uC would only be momentary and your battery life would depend on the number of times you planned on switching the circuit.

Could you add a powersupply/transformer that fed the uC from your mains supply?

P.S. This was my first time using circuit lab and had to rush to keep it in the free demo time!

[image]

Comment: You might want to point out to Lucas that none of the relays in your answer are latching relays.  Also, Lucas, if you use @Joshyp00's answer, you need to be careful about making sure you are using a continuous duty relay (one that is continuously left on). I would prefer to use a "Lamp Relay" that has 2 coils.  One for activating (closing) the relay and another to deactivate (opening) the relay.  Then wire one of the SSRs to each coil.  That way you don't need to worry about getting a continuous active relay.  Or burning the extra power.

Comment: @Joshyp00 No I can't add a power supply, I only have one phase wire that it will go to directly to the light and anything that I put in the switch circuit it will be in series with the light. Except for the uC which will be drawing his power from the battery. In the schematic the coil of the lamp relay is connected directly to the neutral wire so is not viable.

Comment: @st2000 I got it, but the coil of the relay would have to be in series with the lamp, I don't have access to the circuit in the lamp. All I have is the phase which is going directly to the lamp. So I can't control the coil from power coming from the grid.

Comment: I think you have backed your self into a situation that can not be easily solved.  You can try leaching power off the mains hot and load lines.  But this technique depends heavily on the type of load.  If an incandescent bulb it should be easy.  If a high efficiency bulb this may or may not work.  I would, at this point, seriously consider changing the scope of the project.  As with its current constraints it sounds like it will only work for a limited number of operations (really small power source) or for only very specific loads (probably incandescent (which are nearly obsolete) ) bulbs.

Comment: @st2000 what about using a low power latch relay, which only requires power to change state? Since the current to switch the relay is too high i would use capacitors so the current wouldn't drain the battery. The coin cell has a lot of power but it can't sustain high currents.

Comment: I think you are talking about using a charge pump circuit or even a boost switching power supply to charge up a capacitor which you will in turn use to momentarily power a latching relay.  This isn't my area of expertise.  However, you sound like you are building a complex circuit which, from our point of view, has several simpler, more dependable and cheaper solutions.

Comment: @st2000 yeah searching in the internet i founded a more suitable solution, this is a circuit using two N mosfet as a AC switch: http://tinyurl.com/j2rzoev

The mosfet in the design is exaggerated (Beta=200 to allow great amperage, with Vth=1.5v) but i will be using him to switch a triac.